# An Equivalence Relation

Tags: ring-theory

**Theorem.** Let $I$ and $J$ be ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ (where $\omega$ is a primitive $p$th root of unity) and define the relation $I\sim J$ if and only if $aI=bJ$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. Then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

*My Proof*. Clearly, the relation is reflexive ($aI=aI$) and symmetric (if $aI=bJ$, then $bJ=aI$). Transitivity is the bit I am stuck with:

If $aI=bJ$ and $bJ=cK$ (for another ideal $K$ and a $c\in\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$), then is it just as simple as this to say that $aI=cK$? That seems WAY too easy.

Could somebody tell me if and where I have gone wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You need to show that if $aA=bB$ and $rB=sC$ then $A\sim C$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown. Ah, thanks, that makes more sense. So $aA=bB$ and $rB=sC$, then $raA=rbB=brB=bsC$ and since $ra,bs\in\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, this shows it is transitive?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I am also trying to show that there are infinitely many equivalences classes under this relation. How do I do that?

Comment: You can't: the class-group is finite.

Comment: Oh yes, In fact, I did know that. It's the class number. Misreading a question can cause a lot of confusion...

Comment: In that case, how do I show that the class group is finite?

Comment: Look up a text on algebraic number theory.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ok thank you. I thought I would have to resort to that. I do have access to (a very long) proof - I was hoping there would be a nicer way. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @egreg. Noted, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a very common error and it's good you felt something hairy was going on.

---

Another example:

> Two elements $a$ and $b$ of a domain $R$ are said to be *associate*, written $a\sim b$, if there exists $u\in R$ invertible such that $a=bu$.
>   Prove this is an equivalence relation.

Reflexivity: $a=a1$.

Symmetry: Suppose $a\sim b$, that is, $a=bu$ with $u$ invertible; then $b=au^{-1}$ and so $b\sim a$.

Transitivity: Suppose $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$, that is, $a=bu$ and $b=c\color{red}{u}$, with $u$ invertible. Then $a=bu=cu^2$ and $u^2$ is invertible, so $a\sim c$.

***Error!*** We can only say that $b=c\color{green}{v}$, for some invertible $v$. Note that, with the same error, one could also have said $c=bu$ (because of symmetry), so it would be $a=c$, which is generally false.

---

In your case you can say that $aI=bJ$ and $cJ=dK$, for some $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. But then $acI=bcJ$ and $bcJ=bdK$, so $(ac)I=(bd)K$.